# Can we have a Model with a lot of properties (say 30) while avoiding the exploding indexes pitfall?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was thinking that maybe you can have the index.yaml only specify certain indexes (not all the possible ones that GAE automatically does for you).

If that's not a good idea, what is another way of dealing with storing large amount of properties other than storing extra properties as a serialized object in a blob property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Exploding indexes happen when you have [multiple properties that contain "multiple values"](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes), i.e. an entity with MULTIPLE list properties AND those properties are listed in a composite index. In this case index entry is created for each list property value combination. In different words: index entries created equals a product of list properties size. So a list property with 20 entries and another list property with 30 entries would create, when BOTH listed in index.yaml under one compound index, 600 index entries.
2. Exploding indexes do not happen for simple (non-list) properties, or if there is only one list property in entity.
3. Exploding indexes also do not happen if you do not create a compound index in your index.yaml file, listing at least two list properties in same index.
4. If you have a lot of properties and you do not need to query upon them, than you can simply put them in a list or two parallel lists (to simulate map), or serialize them. The simplest would be two two parallel lists: this is done automatically for you if you use `objectify` with [embedded classes](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded).

Comment: Note 1 is very misleading. 'Exploding indexes' only occur when you have multiple list properties (or the same list property referenced multiple times) in a composite index. Though it says that at the end, the rest of the point reads like the mere presence of multiple list properties is sufficient.

Comment: Just to double check, if I have just one property that is a list, and the query is only based on this list propert- nothing else. And let's say that the entries for this model have varying amount of values, one of which has 100 values. How many index entries is there? 100? That would still be a lot of index entries, right? Even though it wouldn't fall into the above 4 conditions and be a case of exploding indexes...

Answer (score 4):

The [new improved query planner](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection.html) should generate optimized index definitions.

Note that you can set a property as unindexed by using `indexed=False` in [python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Unindexed_Properties) or `Entity.setUnindexedProperty` in [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Unindexed_Properties).

Comment: Thanks so much. Didn't know about the indexed=false property!